# Android Studio - Old commands like httpparams, httpclient are not working anymore

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Some commands like `HttpClient` or `HttpPost` are not working. Could anyone help me?

```js
 @Override
    protected users doInBackground(Void... params){
        Map<String, String> dataToSend = new HashMap<>();
        dataToSend.put("x", users.x + "");
        dataToSend.put("y", users.y);

        URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADRESS);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        HttpParams httpRequestPramas = new BasicHttpParams();
        conn.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestPramas, CONNECTION_TIME);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestPramas, CONNECTION_TIME);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestPramas);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADRESS + "login.php");

        users returnedusers = null;
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            if (jObject.length() == 0){
                users = null;
            }else{
                String vorname = jObject.getString("y");
                int kundennummer = jObject.getInt("x");

                returnedusers = new users(users.y, users.x);

            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnedusers;
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Imports are present?

Comment: Standard procedure: Check gardle,import,resync,clean,rebuild

Comment: not working? or marked as deprecated? .... alse why are you using both URLConnection  and apache at the same time? ... *commands like "HttpClient"* did you mean classes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing there, You are mixing app apache HttpClient which is deprecated in Android SDK and HttpUrlConnection which is standard in Android SDK. Could you please explain a little bit more about your setup and why?

Comment: @Selvin
Some of them are marked as deprecated.

Comment: @Rene M. I am trying to do this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGk_EdI5qj0 ~19:40min

Comment: Then please explain this here in your question, otherwise the trolls will down vote your question till its gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.sitedemo.service.php");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("username", "maven")
                                       .appendQueryParameter("password", "123");
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(query);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();

InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
response = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
```

ref- [android.net.Uri.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html)